# Display iframe youtube video in Shadowbox/Fancybox in wordprsss

Tags: youtube, fancybox, shadowbox

I have been looking and looking for a solution but can not find one to opening

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/A6XUVjK9W4o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The reason for wanting to open in this format is the generated image link.

Thanks

Comment: so, what is the question? ...are you using fancybox or shadowbox? ... where is your jQuery code? .... and last one : how do you pretend to get help without providing such information? unless you think we can figure it out what is in your mind ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of use embed code, i use only the embed link that wrap an image so when i click the image a shadowbox popup opens with the video inside